# Nginx, Express and Vuejs: Some assets files takes too long to load

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, nginx

I have Nginx, Express (node) and Vuejs setup on my server.

The Express server just sends the Vuejs build directly when I visit my website. Everything works, except that some files (not all of them) takes 1 min before reaching my browser.

I also have those "errors" in Nginx:

```
2023/09/13 19:32:45 [error] 3930470#3930470: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: **.***.**.***, server: www.wradion.dev, request: "GET /assets/index.a2f3249e.css HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://162.255.119.151:8080/assets/index.a2f3249e.css", host: "www.wradion.dev", referrer: "https://www.wradion.dev/xxxxxx"
2023/09/13 19:32:46 [error] 3930470#3930470: *5 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: **.***.**.***, server: www.wradion.dev, request: "GET /assets/vendor.90419635.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://162.255.119.151:8080/assets/vendor.90419635.js", host: "www.wradion.dev", referrer: "https://www.wradion.dev/xxxxxx"
```

This doesn't cause the website to malfunction, it's just there, indicating that it's trying to do something (I don't know what), then fails after a 1 min timeout, then serve my Vuejs assets normally.

Here is my Nginx sites-enabled/default, it's probably the issue because I don't really fully understand how everything works (especially regarding redirection non-www, http, ...):

```
server {
        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen       443 ssl default;
        listen  [::]:443 ssl default;

        # certbot certificates conf

        root /var/www/wradion_dev/frontend/dist;

        server_name www.wradion.dev;

        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://wradion.dev:8080;
        }

        location /socket.io {
                proxy_pass http://wradion.dev:8090;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

# Redirect non-www to www
server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        listen  [::]:443 ssl;

        # certbot certificates conf

        server_name wradion.dev;

        return 301 https://www.wradion.dev$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name _;
}
```

Basically I want to understand what exactly it's doing to just don't do it and serve my assets directly. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

I replaced the URL with local IP:

```
proxy_pass http://wradion.dev:8080;
...
proxy_pass http://wradion.dev:8090;
```

To:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
...
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
```